# How to perform panel Dynamic Fixed Effects (fe) Model with xtpmg?

Tags: stata

I'm using the Stata command [xtpmg](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0125) that performs Pooled Mean-Group, Mean-Group, and Dynamic Fixed Effects Models.

The Pooled Mean-Group Model returns estimates, but the  Dynamic Fixed Effects Model returns "option fe not allowed".

```
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/j/jasa2.dta, clear
xtpmg d.c d.y d.pi, lr(l.c y pi) pmg
```

Returns estimates

```
xtpmg d.c d.y d.pi, lr(l.c y pi) fe
```

Returns **option fe not allowed**

Comment: based on the article you linked to, the option for dynamic fixed effects is `dfe`, not `fe`.. does it make a difference by running it with `dfe` in place of `fe`?

Comment: `xtpmg` is a user-written command. There might be an error within the documentation `help xtpmg`, so try the `dfe` option as implied by the source code (`viewsource xtpmg`) and the Stata Journal article. Try contacting the authors to comment on the issue.

Comment: Yes option dfe works, I should have read the article rather than rush to the example in the help file. I have written an email to  Edward Blackburne and Mark Frank suggesting to correct the help file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xtpmg` is a user-written command (`ssc describe xtpmg`).

There seems to be an error in the corresponding `help` file, so try the `dfe` option as implied by the source code (`viewsource xtpmg.ado`) and the Stata Journal article you reference.

Try contacting the authors to comment on the issue.

Comment: The typo is in the help file on SSC, but in the *Stata Journal* version.